# Kronig-Penney model in the presence of small external potential perturbation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, crystals

[Kronig-Penney model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice) in 1D is a nice and simple way to understand the physics of
a crystal lattice. Usually, one relies on using the [Bloch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem) to obtain the dispersion relation and associated wave states.

A particularly simple version of the problem is when we assume that the periodic potential is a Dirac comb:

$$ V_0(x) = A \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x - a n)\, . $$

I was wondering, what happens when we add a small perturbation to this potential?
In other words, when I change the potential to

$$ V_0(x) \to V(x) = V_0(x) + \delta V(x), $$

where e.g. $\delta V(x)$ can be some small sinusoidal change with the wavelength with $\lambda \gg a$.